# MySQL - Select em dois bancos dados comparando colunas

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando fazer uma select em dois bancos de dados diferentes comparando a coluna matricula.

```
select A.matricula, B.matricula from banco1.escolas A JOIN banco2.escola B ...
```

O banco1 é o mais completo. Eu gostaria de saber quais matriculas constam no banco1 e não no banco2.

Eu tentei da seguinte forma:

```
select A.matricula, B.matricula from banco1.escolas A JOIN banco2.escola B where A.matricula <> B.matricula
```

Mas não funcionou. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua query está quase certa, por apenas um detalhe:

> O banco1 é o mais completo. Eu gostaria de saber quais matriculas
> constam no banco1 e não no banco2.

Se um banco tem dados que no outro não tem, não deve usar o `INNER JOIN`. Esse *join* retorna os dados **se exitir em ambas as tabelas**. No seu exemplo, foi um INNER JOIN por causa do `WHERE`.

Como o banco1 possui mais dados, use um `LEFT JOIN`, pois no commando join ele está a esquerda (left) e vai retornar os dados em comum assim como os registros que existirem somente no banco1:

```
select A.matricula, B.matricula 
  from banco1.escolas A 
  left join  banco2.escola B on A.matricula = B.matricula
```

Aproveitando, sugiro ler essa **excelente** pergunta e as responstas que tem aqui no site sobre as [diferenças entre inner join e outer join](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

**EDIT:** Para responder ao comentário *"quais matriculas estão no banco1 e não estão no banco2"*: Olhando para a query acima, uma vez que foi feito um `LEFT JOIN`, serão exibidos sempre os registros de "banco1.escolas", e caso não seja encontrado um correspondente em "banco2.escola", o resultado da query irá trazer `NULL` em "B.matricula".

Logo, para retornar o que existe no banco1 e não existe no banco2, aproveitando esse join, basta filtar os registros onde "B.matricula" seja null, por exemplo:

```
select A.matricula, B.matricula 
  from banco1.escolas A 
  left join  banco2.escola B on A.matricula = B.matricula 
 where B.matricula is null;
```

Outra solução seria "retone os dados de banco1.escolas onde **NÃO EXISTA** um correspondente em banco2.escolas", que poderia ser feito usando uma subquery:

```
select A.matricula
  from escolasA A 
 where not exists (select B.matricula
                      from escolasB B 
                      where B.matricula = A.matricula);
```

Comment: Olá @ricardo! Como ficaria o código comparando as matriculas e imprimindo as que constam no banco1 (banco atualizado) e não no banco2? ou seja, quais matriculas estão no banco1 e não estão no banco2. Fiz diversos testes utilizando o exemplo enviado e em todos os casos não consigo o resultado desejado.

Comment: editei a resposta, veja lá :)

Comment: matou! era exatamente isso! obrigado.